# Copy a XML node based on a peer node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a source XML as

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:LookupRecords xmlns:urn="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Services.SearchService" xmlns:a="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <urn:query>
        <a:Headers>
          <a:SearchHeader>
            <a:Name>MAX_RESULTS</a:Name>
            <a:ProviderGuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:ProviderGuid>
            <a:Value>10</a:Value>
          </a:SearchHeader>
          <a:SearchHeader>
            <a:Name>CASHIER</a:Name>
            <a:Value>1706</a:Value>
          </a:SearchHeader>
          <a:SearchHeader>
            <a:Name>RECEIPT_LOOKUP</a:Name>
            <a:Value>CustomerReceipt</a:Value>
          </a:SearchHeader>
        </a:Headers>
        <a:Params>
          <arr:KeyValueOfguidArrayOfQueryParametertmL6yAXy>
            <arr:Key>{4de38819-43bf-4333-a17b-049ec32703c3}</arr:Key>
            <arr:Value>
              <a:QueryParameter>
                <a:Name>TRAINING_MODE</a:Name>
                <a:Value>FALSE</a:Value>
              </a:QueryParameter>
              <a:QueryParameter>
                <a:Name>STORE</a:Name>
                <a:Value>121</a:Value>
              </a:QueryParameter>
              <a:QueryParameter>
                <a:Name>REGISTER</a:Name>
                <a:Value>2</a:Value>
              </a:QueryParameter>
              <a:QueryParameter>
                <a:Name>TRANSACTION_NUMBER</a:Name>
                <a:Value>1843</a:Value>
              </a:QueryParameter>
              <a:QueryParameter>
                <a:Name>TRANSACTION_DATE_YEAR</a:Name>
                <a:Value>2016</a:Value>
              </a:QueryParameter>
              <a:QueryParameter>
                <a:Name>TRANSACTION_DATE_MONTH</a:Name>
                <a:Value>12</a:Value>
              </a:QueryParameter>
              <a:QueryParameter>
                <a:Name>TRANSACTION_DATE_DAY</a:Name>
                <a:Value>20</a:Value>
              </a:QueryParameter>
              <a:QueryParameter>
                <a:Name>CONCEPT</a:Name>
                <a:Value>WS</a:Value>
              </a:QueryParameter>
            </arr:Value>
          </arr:KeyValueOfguidArrayOfQueryParametertmL6yAXy>
        </a:Params>
      </urn:query>
    </urn:LookupRecords>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to get a result XML as

```
<Lookup xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" content="sample string 1" type="sample string 2" pageIndex="sample string 3" pageSize="sample string 4" tranSortOrder="sample string 5">
  <RequestData TrainingModeFlag="False" Store="sample string 1" Operator="sample string 2" Terminal="sample string 3">
    <TRANSACTION_DATE_YEAR>2016</TRANSACTION_DATE_YEAR>
    <TRANSACTION_DATE_MONTH>sample string 15</TRANSACTION_DATE_MONTH>
    <TransactionNumber>sample string 17</TransactionNumber>
  </RequestData>
</Lookup>
```

I am using XSLT To get the same as

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:a="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core"
      version="2.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match = "a:QueryParameter" >  
<xsl:apply-templates select="a:QueryParameter[a:Name='TRANSACTION_NUMBER']/a:Value"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
<Lookup tranSortOrder="sample string 5" 
pageSize="sample string 4" 
pageIndex="sample string 3" 
type="sample string 2" 
content="sample string 1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<RequestData Terminal="sample string 3" 
Operator="sample string 2" 
Store="sample string 1" 
TrainingModeFlag="False">

<OrderNumber>    
</OrderNumber>
<TransactionNumber>
  <xsl:apply-templates />  
</TransactionNumber>
</RequestData>
</Lookup>    
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the Xpath As a:QueryParameter[a:Name='TRANSACTION_NUMBER']/a:Value

I am not getting the desired out put (Which is 1843)

Please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a well-formed XML as the input example.

Comment: Hi, Michael, Updated with well formed XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should correct is your XML.

Note that you use there namespaces for *a* and *arr*, but failed to specify them in the main (*Envelope*) tag.

So I changed the header to:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:a="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core"
    xmlns:arr="urn:dummy">
```

I also inserted `<a:QueryParameter>` just after `<arr:Value>` (apparently you missed this detail).

Now let's move to your XSLT.

One change is that `apply-templates` (at the end) should be limited to `//arr:Value`.
Otherwise you get also all text nodes from other elements.

I made also substantial changes in the template matching `QueryParameter`.

Note the content of each `select` clause:

```
a:QueryParameter[a:Name/text()='...']/a:Value
```

It actually means:

- take child QueryParameter node - `a:QueryParameter`,
- such that - `[...]`,
- it has `a:Name` child node,
- which has text child node - `/text()`,
- equal to a string `='...'`,
- and from this (`QueryParameter`) node take the content of child `a:Value`.

Your mistake is that when you want to compare the content of a node to some value
in a predicate, you must use `text()` to reference the text content of this node.

It is not needed e.g. in `value-of`.

Below you have your XSLT changed by me.

Note also that because I referenced `arr` namespace, I had to add it to the `stylesheet` tag.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:a="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core"
    xmlns:arr="urn:dummy"
    version="2.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="arr:Value" >
  <TRANSACTION_DATE_YEAR>
    <xsl:value-of
      select="a:QueryParameter[a:Name/text()='TRANSACTION_DATE_YEAR']/a:Value"/>
  </TRANSACTION_DATE_YEAR>
  <TRANSACTION_DATE_MONTH>
    <xsl:value-of
      select="a:QueryParameter[a:Name/text()='TRANSACTION_DATE_MONTH']/a:Value"/>
  </TRANSACTION_DATE_MONTH>
  <TransactionNumber>
    <xsl:value-of
      select="a:QueryParameter[a:Name/text()='TRANSACTION_NUMBER']/a:Value"/>
  </TransactionNumber>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
<Lookup tranSortOrder="sample string 5" pageSize="sample string 4" 
pageIndex="sample string 3" type="sample string 2" content="sample string 1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RequestData Terminal="sample string 3" Operator="sample string 2" 
    Store="sample string 1" TrainingModeFlag="False">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//arr:Value"/>
  </RequestData>
</Lookup>    
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Valdi, Thanks for the response I have overcome the mistakes but still unable to get the result as expected.
As the 'a:QueryParameter[a:Name/text()='TRANSACTION_DATE_YEAR']/a:Value' doesn't give the value I wanted. It is giving a blank node instead.

Comment: And what about other nodes (transaction month and number)? Are they transformed correctly? Check your source XML for possible misspellings. Another thing to check: Use any online XSLT transformer (e.g. http://xsltransform.net/). Enter there your (corrected) XML and my XSLT. Before I submitted this answer I cheched it that way.

Comment: Sorry It was my mistake. I had to change the namespace. Thanks a lot for the help...